# OpenCV, How to delete small pixels and fill whole area of interrest

Tags: c++, opencv, pixel, detection

How can I get rid of small wrong detected pixels and fill my area of interrest what is hematoma in my case?

Any ideas?

IMAGE:
http://postimg.org/image/u168qier1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest method is just to find only external contours (function [findContours](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=findcontours#findcontours), use flag `CV_RETR_EXTERNAL`). To avoid detection of very small contours set some threshold value for contour area - drop all contours with area (contour area can be calculated using [contourArea](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=findcontours#double%20contourArea(InputArray%20contour,%20bool%20oriented))) smaller than this threshold.
Alternative approach is to draw all contours on black mat and use morphologic operations - erode/dilation ([link](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html?highlight=erode#void%20erode(InputArray%20src,%20OutputArray%20dst,%20InputArray%20kernel,%20Point%20anchor,%20int%20iterations,%20int%20borderType,%20const%20Scalar&%20borderValue))) to exapnd the contour.

Comment: thank you for your quick answer. I will try it. I am already using function erode and dilate. Perhaps I need to set them up better. Also I was thinking if there is some function what if I would set an area, let's say 3x3, it will check around my missing pixel in the hematoma area and if the surrounding pixels are the same color as I am looking for, that function will fill it.